# Pandas DataFrame Column Names with subscript, superscript, and symbols without using unicode

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried doing this below in visual studio code, but it doesn't work. For example, "$b_{w}$" shows up as $b_{w}$. Anyone knows how to do this without using unicode?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
    {"Section": "12inx30ft", "$b_{w}$": 12, "$\mu^2$": 30},
    {"Section": "8inx47.2ft", "$\alpha_{w}$": 8, "$x^a$": 47.2},
    ]
) 
edited_df = st.experimental_data_editor(df, num_rows="dynamic")
```